# FQL getting a list of non-friend from my current location

Tags: facebook-fql

I would like to know how to get a list of id facebook's user from my current location,

I just did that `SELECT uid , current_location FROM user WHERE current_location = '115175415163151'`

but I get the next error

```
"{
  "error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you just cannot get User's `location` as it requires either `user_location or friends_location` ,  quoting from [User documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) that means you just can't retrieve any User's `location` without User allowing you the required permission.

Secondly you cannot query on fql without using an indexable column in WHERE clause, quoting from [fql documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/)

> Your query must also be indexable, meaning that it queries properties that are marked as indexable in the documentation below.